# How to reset running number ID when the new day come

Tags: vb.net

- i want to print label  with label_id
- label id format contain running number which is 0001 (0001,0002,..)
  -i want to reset the running number to 0001 when the new day come.

can someone give me some ideas or solution regarding my problem?

currently, my system do not reset the running number, here is my source code:

```
If cls_PICS.get_ExistingSequenceNoOld(TextScanPartNo.Text, TextBoxMOQ.Text, TextVendorID.Text) = True Then
    cls_PICS.BOXIDRunningNo(cls_PICS.BoxEnd(0))
        TextStart.Text = cls_PICS.NewBox
    Else
        TextStart.Text = "A00001"
    End If


Public Function get_ExistingSequenceNoOld(ByVal PN As String, ByVal q As String, ByVal vID As String)
      On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   Dim SQL_str As String =
     "SELECT * " & 
     "FROM setup  ORDER BY PrinterDateTime DESC"

    '"SELECT * " &
    '"FROM setup where PartNo='" & PN & "' AND MOQ='" & q & "' AND VendorID='" & vID & "' AND Status <> 'INACTIVE' ORDER BY PrinterDateTime DESC"

    Dim adLWS As New OdbcDataAdapter(SQL_str, cnPICS)
    Dim dsLWS As New DataSet
    adLWS.Fill(dsLWS, "BOXID")

    LWS_CONT = dsLWS.Tables("BOXID").Rows.Count

    If LWS_CONT < 1 Then
        get_ExistingSequenceNoOld = False
        'get_cstTBL_Insert(val)
        Exit Function
    End If
```

This code basically after print the label all the information save to setup table:

```
Public Function InsertBoxIDPrint(ByVal venID As String, ByVal PartNo As String, ByVal Quantity As String, ByVal PDate As String, ByVal Qty As String, ByVal boxID As String, ByVal EmployeeID As String, ByVal qc As String, ByVal DQ As String, ByVal BoxSTART As String, ByVal BoxEND As String, ByVal PC As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'Dim pn As String
    'Dim RefnoP As String
    'Dim curDate As String

    Dim dateL As Date
    Dim date1 As String

    dateL = cls_PICS.get_SERVER_Datetime
    date1 = dateL.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    'curDate = dateL.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

    'If cls_PICS.get_RefNoPrint <> False Then
    '    pn = cls_PICS.RefNoPrint
    '    RefnoP = curDate & "-" & Format((Int(pn) + 1), "000")
    'Else
    '    RefnoP = curDate & "-001"
    'End If

    Dim SQLcmd As New OdbcCommand()
    Dim cnPICS As New OdbcConnection(getPICSConStr)

    SQLcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [setup] (VendorID, PartNo, MOQ, PrinterDateTime, PrintQty, BoxID, PrintBy, QC, DeliveryQty, StartBox, EndBox, PC) " &
        "VALUES ('" &
         venID & "','" &
         PartNo & "','" &
         Quantity & "','" &
         date1 & "','" &
         Qty & "','" &
         boxID & "','" &
         EmployeeID & "','" &
         qc & "','" &
         DQ & "','" &
         BoxSTART & "','" &
         BoxEND & "','" &
         PC & "')"


    SQLcmd.Connection = cnPICS
    SQLcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cnPICS.Open()
    SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cnPICS.Close()


    SQLcmd = Nothing
    InsertBoxIDPrint = True
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:

    InsertBoxIDPrint = False

    MsgBox("InsertBoxIDPrint:" & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The current script will not return a new count as long as their is data in the database.  It is basing the count on the rows in the database.  I would create a new table in the database just for keeping last print date and current count.  Each time a print is called, it checks the last print date in the table you created.  If they match, continue with todays count and increase todays count by one, else append new start date to table and begin count at 0 or 1, depending on if you are issuing the print immediately, or having the counter increase during the print.

Your new table should have two fields:  PrintDate, PrintCounter

If this is server side software, the variables for PrintDate and PrintCounter could be scripted as variables, however upon reset of the server the variables would be lost, unless you choose to write them to a file instead of the database.

Below is some sample code you could try.  My VB skills are lacking.

```
adLWS.Fill(dsLWS, "date1")

    Dim lastRecord As Int32
    Dim lastDate As String
    lastRecord = dsLWS.Tables("date1").Rows.Count - 1
    lastDate = dsLWS.Tables("date1").Rows.Item(lastRecord).Item("date1")


    If Today.Date > CDate(lastDate).Date Then
        get_ExistingSequenceNoOld = False
    Else
        get_ExistingSequenceNoOld = True
    End If
```

Comment: If the table BOXID has a date field, it would also be possible to reset by ordering table by date, pulling last date record, and comparing that record to the current time of the system.  If they match (using only mm/dd/yyyy format) then continue count, otherwise reset count.  Can you provide us with the fields for the BOXID table?

Comment: Thank you.  I will get you a response soon.

Comment: I already try your code. It works if new day come but if i print it at the same day the running no start with 00001 again. should be it is continue the running no in the same day. How?Can you help me?

Comment: can you help me? urgent..please help me. @Paul Hill